# Mocking Rest Exchange for Void API

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit, mockito

i'm trying to Mock the below rest call

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<User>(user), void.class);
```

here is the JUNIT

```
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Matchers.any(), Matchers.eq(HttpMethod.PUT), Matchers.any(HttpEntity.class), Matchers.eq(Void.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED));
```

but the problem is when i debugged the code . it's always returning NULL  even if i throw an exception from the mock.

i'm not sure what i am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

This is because the classes `Void` and `void.class` are different:

```
Class<?> c1 = void.class;
Class<?> c2 = Void.class;
System.out.println(c1.equals(c2));
```

prints `false`.

Try the following:

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Matchers.any(),
                                   Matchers.eq(HttpMethod.PUT),
                                   Matchers.any(HttpEntity.class),
                                   Matchers.eq(void.class)))
  .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED));
```

Comment: thanks for reply , but that didn't help  , it's just returned null